# How to define mongoose schema ref fields with typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I use following code for schema definition:

```
import { Prop, Schema } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Types } from 'mongoose';

@Schema({ collection: 'templates' })
export class Template {
    @Prop({
        type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
        ref: User.id,
        required: true,
    })
    public user: Types.ObjectId;

    // other fields...
}
```

I want to have User fields (user: User => user.name) when populate template entity but I have type restriction:

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'ObjectId'

Answer (score 0):

in typescript (nest-js), i use virtuals instead like this:

```
Schema.virtual('YOUR_VIRTUAL_NAME', {
  ref: 'User',
  localField: 'userOnlyReservableId',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true,
});
```

remember adding in schema:

```
@Schema({ toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true } })
```

and last populate the virtual after find:

```
model.find({}).populate('YOUR_VIRTUAL_NAME')
```